# check if form is dirty on state change start using run() function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am using angular ui-router to defines states, i wish to check if form in the current state is dirty and prompt user when user navigates between ui-router states. When user tries to navigate from one state to another i want to check if the form in the current state is pristine and prompt him if he really wants to propagate to next form. I have written a common run function which will take care of this.

```
angular.module('module')
.run(function ($rootScope, $compile, $templateRequest) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (fromState.name.length > 0) {
            $templateRequest(fromState.templateUrl)
                .then(function (html) {
                    var compiledElement = $compile(html)($rootScope);
                    console.log(compiledElement.find('form'));
                });

        }
        if (fromState.name.length > 0 && !confirm('You have unsaved changes, go back?'))
            event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I want to get the scope of the current UI-Router state so that i can check the forms pristine or any other means to know if the form in the current state is dirty or not.